# Disable Snipcart full-page cart

Tags: html, css, snipcart

Is it possible to disable Snipcart's full-page cart? I have set `data-config-modal-style="side"` [like the docs says to](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/setup/installation) but on smaller screens the cart still opens the full page-cart.

I don't want to have to design two different carts to look the same.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they automatically switch to full-page view in small screens. What you can do is override that behavior with the same styles they are using for `side-modal`. Add this to your global `css`:

```css
.snipcart-modal__container {
  width: 35% !important;
  max-width: 540px !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}

.snipcart-modal__container.snipcart-layout--large {
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

You can also remove `data-config-modal-style="side"` from HTML now, since you don't need it anymore.

Comment: This is for sure a way but I prefer the content/html in the side-cart which differs from the full page cart.

Comment: You can not achieve this through HTML unless they support it (you should send them direct message). The styles that I putted as answer are Snipcart's style for side-cart.

Comment: Yes I'm hoping they see this question :) This css will also effect the next page, the checkout, which would be good to keep full width.

Comment: You are right. I didn't consider it. I updated my answer. Can you try it now?